# TextAngular individual toolbars for each editor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, textangular

I am using textAngular and as per the instructions in the textAnuglarSetup have specified my own toolbar like so:

```
     taOptions.toolbar = [
['bold', 'italics', 'underline', 'ul', 'ol', 'redo', 'undo', 'insertLink'],
];
```

We are using multiple instances of textAngular throughout the site. I would like to pass a different toolbars to certain instances of TA (as I do not want each instance to have the same text formatting options)

for example:

```
 taOptions.toolbar2 = [
['bold', 'italics', 'underline'],
];
```

I'm thinking that I should be looking to somehow pass toolbar manually to each textAngular directive so I can specify which one it should use?

I'm a bit stuck so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I think my answer is esentially in the mutliple toolbars heading here https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Customising-The-Toolbar - However i'm still unsure of how to implement

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was as simple as passing the desired toolbar array straight into the text-angular directive like so:

```
ta-toolbar="[[\'bold\', \'italics\', \'underline\', \'redo\', \'undo\', \'insertLink\']]"
```

As I have text-angular wrapped in my own directive, I am just exposing the attributes scope and passing in my toolbar array